# Eclipse: What is this outline on top of the editor called? How can I change it's coloring or disable it?

Tags: java, eclipse

[image: Eclipse Screenshot]

I've used Eclipse for 10+ years, and today I did something I have no idea how to undo. No amount of right clicking or Googling has given me an answer, so I'm humbly asking here.

Somehow I managed to enable an outline header on the editor view. It's not terrible, but since it doesn't adhere to the Eclipse theme, it's an eyesore. What is it called? How can I disable it, and or fix the color theme? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is called ***Java Editor Breadcrumb*** (see [Eclipse Help](https://help.eclipse.org/oxygen/topic/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/ref-java-editor-breadcrumb.htm)).

You can disable the breadcrumb by clicking on the [image] icon in the main toolbar.

The colors of the *Java Editor Breadcrumb* cannot be changed:
see [Eclipse bug 465666 - [breadcrumb] Button background not styled in dark theme](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=465666).

**Update:** Since Eclipse 2018-09 (4.9) this issue is fixed and the *Java Editor Breadcrumb* supports also the dark theme (see [Eclipse 4.9 - New and Noteworthy](https://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/news/4.9/jdt.php#breadcrumb-dark)).

Comment: @KimchiMan This issue has already been fixed two releases ago (see my edited answer). Please upgrade.

Comment: Ah, then the bug still exists in Spring Tool Suite

Answer (score 2):

Try changing your theme. 
Window->Preferences
Select Classic theme and select the default option for Color and Font theme.

Answer (score 2):

Try resetting your perspective in Window>Perspective>Reset Perspective. If this doesn't work then you can reset your theme.